# How to add padding to Rabin Encryption in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, security, padding, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to implement the Rabin Cryptosystem in C# but I'm stuck in the part where I have to add a padding to my message in order to have a secure Cryptosystem with OAEP or PKCS#1. Which are the implementation steps? I'm using the Bouncy Castle's Library.

```
// Encrypt data using public key
public byte[] PublicEncryption(byte[] data)
{
    // Converting the byte array data into a BigInteger instance
       BigInteger bnData = new BigInteger(data);

    // (bnData ^ Exponent) % Modulus - This Encrypt the data using the public Exponent
       BigInteger encData = bnData.ModPow(new BigInteger("2"), _n);
       return GetBytes(encData.ToString());
}
```

> Example (Rabin public-key encryption with artificially small
>   parameters) Key generation. Entity A chooses the primes p = 277, q =
>   331, and computes n = pq =
>   91687. A’s public key is n = 91687, while A’s private key is (p = 277, q = 331).
>
> Encryption. Suppose that the last six bits of original
>   messages are required to be replicated prior to encryption (cf. Note
>   8.14(i)). 
>   In order to encrypt the 10-bit message m = 1001111001, B replicates the last six bits of m to obtain the 16-bit message m = 1001111001111001, which in 
>   decimal notation is m = 40569. B then computes c = m2 mod n = 405692 mod 91687 
>   = 62111 and sends this to A.
>
> Decryption. To decrypt c, A uses Algorithm 3.44 and her knowledge of
>   the factors of n to compute the four square roots of c mod n: m1 =
>   69654, m2 = 22033, m3 = 40569, m4 = 51118, which in binary are m1 =
>   10001000000010110, m2 = 101011000010001, m3 = 1001111001111001, m4 =
>   1100011110101110. 
>   Since only m3 has the required redundancy, A decrypts c to m3 and
>   recovers the original message m = 1001111001

Comment: Code? It is very hard/impossible without it.